# Create User authentication in a C# client application

Tags: c#, authentication, client

So I wrote quite a few ASP.NET web applications and there I often used the forms authentication. Now I need to do the same but in a client application. What would be the best way to create something like this?

I was searching for it for some time now but I didn't find something that I could implement in my project. I just need to have a login screen and only when it is valid with the user logins I created I should be able to use the complete application.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several approaches that you could take. If the application is internally distributed you could use a database connection to something like SQL Server where you would have accounts set up to validate against. If the distribution is external you may want to consider setting up a server and using socket connections in your application to make calls to your server(again storing account information in a back end database) to validate users.

Comment: Well it would be a SQL Server but how can I ensure best security on it?
I mean from the connectionstring and to the connection itself.

Comment: I would look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 I'm not overly familiar with secure socket connections. If you don't like SslStreams you could also consider implementing your own encryption for the data you send across the socket. Asymmetric encryption like RSA is secure, and if you don't feel like writing it yourself I'm sure you could find an open source library.

Answer (score 0):

I remember using ASP.NET Identity for that purpose. Was very easy and everything is pretty much ready.

> ASP.NET Core Identity is a membership system that adds login
>   functionality to ASP.NET Core apps. Users can create an account with
>   the login information stored in Identity or they can use an external
>   login provider

[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)